# php array i have an array and i need to place some values in the array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an function called send message

```
function sendMessage(){
    $content = array(
        "en" => 'value1'
    );
    $headings   = array(
        "en" => 'value2'
    );
    $hashes_array = array();

    fields = array(
        'app_id' => "31fe2347-5f39-4d9f-2222-79bf542f00f9",
        'included_segments' => array(
            'All'
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        'contents' => $content,
        'headings' => $headings,
        'url' => 'http://www.999999.in/view.php?id=[id]',
        'chrome_web_image'  => 'http://www.99999.in/admin/user_images/[userPic]',        
    );
```

And I have an array ready

```
Array(
    [id] => 498
    [value2] => యూట్యూబ్‌లో “భరత్ అనే నేను” అన్ కట్ సీన్లు..!
    [value1] => కొరటాల శివ దర్శకత్వం లో సూ...
    [value3] => 525722.jpg
)
```

Now just I need to place array values in function

Please help me on this I tried all echo values

Comment: I do not understand... Can you be clearer?

Comment: i have a php function and i need to insert values on the function from array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the array as an argument to the function, then access the elements.

```
function sendMessage($array) {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => $array['value1']
        );
    $headings   = array(
        "en" => $array['value2']
        );
    $hashes_array = array();

    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "31fe2347-5f39-4d9f-2222-79bf542f00f9",
        'included_segments' => array(
            'All'
            ),
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
            ),
        'contents' => $content,
        'headings' => $headings,
        'url' => 'http://www.999999.in/view.php?id=' . $array['id'],
        'chrome_web_image'  => 'http://www.99999.in/admin/user_images/' . $array['value3'],        

        );
    print_r($fields);
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/IFVWqI)

Comment: actually this is not worked .. this is One-signal API Script by which we are tiring to send push notifications

Comment: How isn't it working? Are you calling the function with your array as the argument?

Comment: simple array already ready like  Array ( [id] => 426 [headings] => hai! [content] => Hello. [userPic] => 250776.jpg )  and i need to insert these values in to function called function sendMessage() {
    $content      = array(
        "en" => content
        );
    $headings   = array(
        "en" => headings
        );
    $hashes_array = array();

Comment: actually i have a values trrough url http://www.999999.in/gistfile1.php?value3d=499&value1=Hello Brother...&valu2=825623.jpg

Comment: It doesn't matter where the data comes from. Once it's in the array, you just access it from there.

Comment: `sendMessage($_GET)` will process the parameters from the URL.

Comment: not working sendMessage($_GET) i cant able to get values and insert the same in function

Comment: I can't understand why it's not working for you. Are you sure the array keys in the function match the URL parameters?

Comment: yes the are maching www dot 999999.in/gistfile1.php?id=498&value1=Hello Brother&value2=525722.jpg

Comment: http://www.999999.in/gistfile1.php?id=500&Value1=Good Morning&Value2=Hello Brother..&value3=527325.jpg  i need to insert these values into the function send message with this values

Comment: It should just work. I think you need to start doing your own debugging, I can't figure out what's different on your system.

Comment: Is it `value1=` or `Value1=`? PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: very simple sir i am getting values from url as i mentioned in earlier one now i need values into this function where value1 = url data value1

Comment: Yes,it's very simple. The URL parameters get put into the `$_GET` array automatically by PHP. If you pass it as an argument to `sendMessage()`, you should be able to access them inside the function. I don't know why it's not working for you. Use `var_dump()` statements to examine the data.

Comment: I'm not going to spend all day teaching you how to debug PHP scripts. You should know how to do that already.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.. Sir.. for guiding me in this project and i am very happy that i got the output for which i expected only because of you.. thanks a lot once again

Comment: Thanks a Lot.. Sir.. for guiding me in this project and i am very happy that i got the output for which i expected only because of you.. thanks a lot once again

Comment: Done Thanks i got the answer and that is only because of you.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$valueArray = ['id' => 498, 'value2' => 'యూట్యూబ్‌లో “భరత్ అనే నేను” అన్ కట్ సీన్లు..!', 'value1' => 'కొరటాల శివ దర్శకత్వం లో సూ... ', 'value3' => '525722.jpg'];
```

*output*

```
Array
(
    [id] => 498
    [value2] => యూట్యూబ్‌లో “భరత్ అనే నేను” అన్ కట్ సీన్లు..!
    [value1] => కొరటాల శివ దర్శకత్వం లో సూ... 
    [value3] => 525722.jpg
)
```

update your function with following code

```
function sendMessage($valueArray){
    extract($valueArray);
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "31fe2347-5f39-4d9f-2222-79bf542f00f9",
        'included_segments' => array('All' ),
        'data' => array( "foo" => "bar" ),
        'contents' => array( "en" => $value1 ),
        'headings' => array( "en" => $value2 ),
        'url' => 'http://www.999999.in/view.php?id=[id]',
        'chrome_web_image'  => 'http://www.99999.in/admin/user_images/[userPic]',        
    ); 

    print_r($fields);
}
```

**pass the array parameter to the function**

```
sendMessage($valueArray);
```

*output*

```
Array
(
    [app_id] => 31fe2347-5f39-4d9f-2222-79bf542f00f9
    [included_segments] => Array
        (
            [0] => All
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [contents] => Array
        (
            [en] => కొరటాల శివ దర్శకత్వం లో సూ... 
        )

    [headings] => Array
        (
            [en] => యూట్యూబ్‌లో “భరత్ అనే నేను” అన్ కట్ సీన్లు..!
        )

    [url] => http://www.999999.in/view.php?id=[id]
    [chrome_web_image] => http://www.99999.in/admin/user_images/[userPic]
)
```